# Visual Studio Code Theme Color Customization

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change color of primitive types in visual studio code. I changed the colors of types like

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "numbers": "#101010",
    "strings": "#A31515",
    "types": "#2B91AF", // this line changes all types colors include primitive types 
     "primitive_types": "#0000FF" // i looking for a property like this line, but there is no property like in this scope 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simple token colors are not enough, you need to be more specific, with `textMateRules`.

A few days ago I answered in a similar thread, maybe it will guide you and let you solve your problem.

Here is it:

- [How to set syntax highlighting for Dart variable in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132498/how-to-set-syntax-highlighting-for-dart-variable-in-visual-studio-code/56375895#56375895)