# How to set syntax highlighting for Dart variable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: dart, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, material-design

I am using Visual Studio Code for coding Dart with Flutter. I installed Dart and Flutter plugins as well as the Material theme from Matta Astorino. The problem is I can't specifically set the syntax highlight of my variables with Dart language using the Material Theme Ocean High Contrast color theme.

The settings i used:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme Ocean High Contrast]": {
    "comments": "#229977",
    "variables": "#ffffff"
    }
  },
```

[image: 1] -Dart

From the picture above, the comments syntax highlighting seems to work fine but the syntax highlighting for variables is still showing in grey (which supposed to be white).

[image: 1] -JavaScript

In JavaScript, it seems to work fine.

Please help on these Dart syntax highlighting for VSCode Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Dart, but i can say that, sometimes you have to be more specific with setting syntax scope colors.

First of all - you need to know what the scope is. To do this, please run **Inspect TM Scopes**.

[image]

**Here you have described how to do it:**

- https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_new-textmate-scope-inspector-widget

**To understand better, it is good to read:**

- https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars 12.4 Naming Conventions
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

**Sublime Text have a good explanation too:**

- https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html

**Ok, and now:**

When you find out what the scope is, then you have to create or overwrite it.
Example:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[My Theme Name]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "name": "Entity",
                    "scope": "entity.name",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FFC66D"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

**If you will create more and more new scopes, remember that:**

- *being too specific will result in a color scheme that often only looks good for one or two syntaxes.*

Comment: it works, figured it out with your textMateRules. thumbs up

Comment: @brendan VSCode does not seem to have a scope for variables. How did you do it?

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui from the answer above, you can see that after you inspect scope, you will find the scope name and apply the textMateRules for the scope. Eg: In dart, the variable is "source" in VSCode, hence you can set textMateRules to overwrite settings for "source" scope.

Comment: @brendan  to be honestly I agree with Dimitrie, the variable is described as "source.dart" but every thing is, it's like "source.dart" is the root! Example: a Class is defined as "support.class.dart" and also "source.dart" so setting this will set an overall color when it have no other definition!

Comment: I Have addressed an issue onto the project https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2237

Comment: @Daniel ohh.. I haven really met that source.dart. But good that you raised an issue on their github.